# Name changes remain in revision history

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-accounts

User [Forgiver](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9467/forgiver) recently changed their name from Moderator (follow the discussion on [User named Moderator](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2446/5764)). While *everything* on the site now reflects the updated user name wherever it's displayed (comments, old/new posts, etc) the [revision history](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2448/5764) display (not the actual revision history) still uses the older/obsolete name:

[image]

Comment: See [Do old usernames stick to CW posts by design?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47474) on Meta.SO.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: While the premise is the same, all their names seem to have changed. Ours still show that `Moderator` "owns" the [CW post](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2448/5764). I wonder why that is...

Comment: I can't say more than Popular Demand - see [the accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110197) to his own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been designated [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) [on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47474/168244). And, while the questions linked there have been successfully adjusted to reflect updated user names, some posts still hold an incorrect username in the revision history (like the one linked in the question).